# jquery popup function does not work in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I think there is something wrong with my selectors that make my jquery popup script not working in IE, (FF and chrome is OK)

edit: what happens in IE is that the fade displays but no popup.

javasctipt

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("a[name*='add-ad-to-']").click(function () {
        var divname= this.name;
        $("#"+divname).slideDown("slow");

        $('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>');
        $('#fade').css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}).fadeIn();

        return false;
    });


});
```

html (dynamically generated, probably nothing wrong there since FF and chrome works fine)

```
    //the link
        echo'<a class="noul" name="add-ad-to-'.$value.'" href="#">Link</a>';

   //the popup   
        echo'<div class="box-add lucida" id="add-ad-to-'.$value.'" style="display:none;">

            //content

        </div>';
```

edit:

here is the css but I do not think that is the problem

```
 #fade {display:none;background:#000;position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0;width: 100%; height: 100%;opacity: .80;z-index: 9999;}
.box-add{position:absolute;left:110px;top:-140px;z-index:99999;padding:30px 40px 10px 40px;background-color:#FFF;border:5px solid #888;text-align:left;color:#555;font-size:11px;font-weight:normal;line-height:22px;width:500px;}
```

Comment: what exactly version of IE are you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you'll have trouble using the same value for a `name` on an `a` element and an `id` on a `div`. Suggest adding something to the name when determining the `id` for the `div`, e.g.:

```
$("#div-"+divname).slideDown("slow");
```

(And change the HTML accordingly, of course.)

This is because [IE has issues with conflating namespaces](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/by-any-other-name-would-smell-as-sweet.html) and tends to dump `name`s in with `id`s. For instance, [try this example](http://jsbin.com/uzura3/2) in Chrome or Firefox vs. IE:

HTML:

```
<a name='foo'>This is the foo anchor</a>
<div id='foo'>This is the foo element</div>
<a name='bar'>This is the bar anchor</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
var foo = document.getElementById('foo'),
    bar = document.getElementById('bar');
display("foo.tagName = " + foo.tagName);
display("bar.tagName = " + (bar ? bar.tagName : "(none)"));
```

Correct output:

```
foo.tagName = DIV
bar.tagName = (none)
```

(The "object" in question for `bar` is `null`.)

IE6 and IE7's output:

```
foo.tagName = A
bar.tagName = A
```

`document.getElementById` should ignore the `a`'s with `name`s on them, but it doesn't on IE6 or IE7, and so IE picks up the anchor instead of the `div`.

Comment: unfortunately it did not work, I have another similar script working with IE so I cant figur this out: //index.php nyheter
 $("a[name*='box-nyhet-']").click(function () {
 var divname= this.name;
 $("#"+divname).slideDown("slow"). This one works fine: siblings().slideUp("slow");
 return false;
 });.  edit: only difference is that html in the IE working example is static and that the function does not include fading. But would that really matter?

Comment: @Joseph: If you make the `name` and `id` values different, I can't see any reason it wouldn't work. Note that which element gets found depends on where it is in the document (in my example, the anchor gets found for `foo` because it's earlier in the document than the `div`; if you put the `div` earlier in the document, it gets found first: http://jsbin.com/uzura3/3), so if you've had something like this working in the past, you've been lucky. Fundamentally, with IE6 and IE7, you **cannot** have both a `name` and an `id` with the same value and have it work reliably.

Comment: it did notwork unfortunately but I will keep the fix since it will prevent other problems. But as an alternative solution I have another working non animating script, how can I mod my javascript so that it performs the simplier function if the click is done with IE browser?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue could be the version if IE you are using, or what version IE thinks it should be using.  JQuery does not support IE 6.  If you are using IE8 you might need to put into your HTML IE=edge to make your browser behave like IE8 instead of automatically emulating an older version.

To do this, add in a meta tag like the one below into the head of your HTML.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" contant="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: could you please explain further how to try this fix. Thanks